# The conditional expectation of a positive random variable is positive

Tags: probability, probability-theory, expectation

How can the following property of conditional expectation can be proven: $X \ge 0 \implies E[X|G] \ge 0$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$$ E[X | G] = \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} xf_{x|g}(x|g)dx $$

$X \geqslant 0$, and $ 0 \leqslant f_{x|g}(x|g) \leqslant 1$ because $f_{x|g}(x|g)$ it is a probability distribution function.  Thus, $E[X | G] \geqslant 0$ because it is a sum of products of non-negative numbers.

The discrete case is similar:

$$ E[X | G] =  \sum_x xf(x|G) $$

Similarly, this is a sum of products of non-negative numbers, so $E[X|G] \geqslant 0$.

Comment: It is not necessary that $X$ has a conditional density. Also, you should not assume the general $G$ can be represented by some random of variable $Y$.

Comment: The y's were typos; fixed.  Thanks for pointing it out.

Comment: The problem still exists, in general $E(X|G)$ doesn't have the integration or summation representation as you presented. You need some measure-theoretic probability knowledge to show this rigorously.

Comment: What does the notation $f_{x|g}(x|g)$ mean?

Comment: The pdf of the conditional distribution X|G

Answer (score 2):

Hint: If $\Bbb E[Y\Bbb 1_E]\ge0$ for every measurable set $E$ then $Y\ge0$ almost surely.

Comment: Could you expand on that. The case $E \in G$ is trivial. But what about a general measurable set?